# changes the powerpoint 2010 notes layout

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I want to have a notes layout with the slides on the left and the corresponding notes on the right. Similar to the handout model with three slides on the left and where you can enter your own notes to the right.

I have been trying to edit the master style for the notes layout but have not succeeded in doing this. A google search did not help me out with this. I simply cannot believe it is not possible, but I cannot find how I can do this.
Can anyone tell me how I can do this in PowerPoint 2010?

I am sure I have to add placeholders in the master style, but which placeholders do I need? Simply copying does not work: I have tried that.

Comment: Do you require three slides per sheet or will a single slide per page with lines suffice for notes?

Comment: One slide with the notes would be enough, most of the time.

Comment: Go into the notes view and rearrange the page to fit your needs.  It only works for a single slide per page.